# "inherit" keyword and "DEPENDS" keyword usage in yocto recipe

Tags: linux, mono, yocto, openembedded

How `inherit` works in yocto?
When to use `inherit` and `DEPENDS` in yocto recipes?

For example, a yocto recipe has:

```
inherit mono
```

other has:

```
DEPENDS = mono
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inherit` is used to add class files. There are usually a lot of different things added by class files such as tasks being defined. You can see what they do by looking at the  **/classes/*.bbclass* files in the different layers. The *mono.bbclass* likely does a lot more than just adding a `DEPENDS`.

In basic terms, the `DEPENDS` variable just says "build mono and have it available" before the current recipe builds. It won't define other interesting things the *mono* class does.

You'd probably want to use the class if you're writing a mono based recipe and need the task definitions and so on. The `DEPENDS` is more appropriate if you just wanted *mono* to be available in your recipes.